# Integration of a Heaviside function

Tags: integration, functions, continuity

I stumbled upon this issue while solving a integration step in a problem as follows:

I  have a discontinuous function   $F_X(x)$ given by
$$F_X(x)=\begin{cases} 
      1 &, 0\leq x< 3 \\\\
      \exp(-\mu x)&, 3\leq x<\infty 
 \end{cases}$$

I could integrate $F_X(x)$  by a piecewise integration. However, if I were to represent this function as $$\displaystyle1-(1-\exp(-\mu x))H(x-3),$$ then I should be able to  integrate as
$$\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} [1-\{1-\exp(-\mu x)\}H(x-3)] dx.$$
Yet,  I couldn't solve it.

Further, I want to integrate rectangular function decomposed as Heaviside functions as follows:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \left(H(t-2)-H(t-3)\right) \,dt$$
I know that that the answer is 1; however, I am unable separate the integral using the linearity of integration and find the answer. Obviously, I am missing some fundamentals here.

Please any advice will be helpful. Is there some silly mistake I am making in the whole question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear as to the specific comment in the OP

> "**It is quite straight forward that the answer is 1, however I am unable separate the integral using the linearity of integration and find the answer.**

But, note that we have for $L>3$

$$\begin{align}
&
\int_0^L (H(t-2)-H(t-3))\,dt
\\\\
&\quad=
\left(\int_0^L H(t-2)\,dt\right)-\left(\int_0^L H(t-3)\,dt \right)
\\\\
&\quad=
(L-2)-(L-3)
\\\\
&\quad=
1
\end{align}$$

Now letting $L\to \infty$, we obtain the expected result.

---

Similarly, for $L>3$, we have

$$\begin{align}
&
\int_0^L \left(1-(1-e^{-\mu x})H(x-3)\right)\,dx 
\\\\
&\quad 
=\int_0^L (1)\,dx- \int_0^L (1-e^{-\mu x})H(x-3)\,dx
\\\\
&\quad 
=L-\int_3^L(1-e^{-\mu x})\,dx
\\\\
&\quad 
=L-(L-3)+\int_3^L e^{-\mu x}\,dx
\\\\
&\quad 
=3+\frac{e^{-3\mu}-e^{-L\mu}}{\mu}
\end{align}
$$

Letting $L\to \infty$ we find that

$$\int_0^\infty \left(1-(1-e^{-\mu x})H(x-3)\right)\,dx=3+\frac{e^{-3\mu}}{\mu}$$

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're assuming $\lim_{x\to\infty}\Big[F(x)+G(x)\Big]=\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x)+\lim_{x\to\infty}G(x)$, although it is not true if the limits on the RHS don't exist. Lets do this step by step. The integral on the interval $\left[0,\infty\right)$ is defined as the limit

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}h(x){\rm d}x=\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{0}^{L}h(x){\rm d}x\tag{1}$$

In your case, denote $f(x)=H(x-2)$ and $g(x)=H(x-3)$. By definition

$$1=\int_{0}^{\infty}\Big[f(x)-g(x)\Big]{\rm d}x=\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{0}^{L}\Big[f(x)-g(x)\Big]{\rm d}x=\tag{2}$$

$$=\lim_{L\to\infty}\Bigg[\int_{0}^{L}f(x){\rm d}x-\int_{0}^{L}g(x){\rm d}x\Bigg]$$

Now the key is that both $\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{0}^{L}f(x){\rm d}x$ and $\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{0}^{L}g(x){\rm d}x$ **don't exist**, so

$$\lim_{L\to\infty}\Bigg[\int_{0}^{L}f(x){\rm d}x-\int_{0}^{L}g(x){\rm d}x\Bigg]\neq\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{0}^{L}f(x){\rm d}x-\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{0}^{L}g(x){\rm d}x\tag{3}$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\Big[f(x)-g(x)\Big]{\rm d}x\neq\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x){\rm d}x-\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x){\rm d}x\tag{4}$$

and in fact the RHS in both Eq. $3$ and $4$ is undefined, since each integral (of $f$ and of $g$) diverges to infinity.

Comment: @MarkViola Your answer doesn't address, in my opinion, the reason **why** linearity fails.

Comment: The OP seems to know that "linearity" fails with the improper Riemann integral.  I provided a way forward that illustrates the correct way to handle the improper Riemann integrals.  But your post is fine.